# Django: Use a variable from a view in a template

Tags: python, django

I want to use the content of a variable with the name "files" in my template in django. My views.py looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

import os


def index(request):
        os.chdir("/home/ubuntu/newproject/static")
        for files in os.listdir("."):
                return render(request, 'sslcert/index.html','files')
```

And my template with the name "index.html" looks like this:

```
<head>
        {% block title %}
        <h3>
                        Following directories are in this folder:
        </h3>
        {% endblock %}
</head>



<body>
        <<(HERE SHOULD BE THE OUTCOME OF THE VARIABLE LIST)>>
</body>
```

Help would be really cool and explanation too :/ I am a real beginner in django and I wish to know how this template and views stuff is connected :) please do not hate on me if this question is really stupid :(

Comment: You're trying to loop rendering of a template. Just pass your `files` to the `render` instead of looping over it.

Comment: Oh damn... I probably get a downvote for this question, but what do you mean by "pass your files to the render" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import os

def index(request):
        os.chdir("/home/ubuntu/newproject/static")
        files = []
        for file in os.listdir("."):
            files.append(file)

        context = {'files':files}
        return render(request, 'sslcert/index.html', context)
```

and then the template:

```
<head>
        {% block title %}
        <h3>
              Following directories are in this folder:
        </h3>
        {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
       {{ files }}
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) But a type error shows up: "render_to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'files'" do not know why :/

Comment: Because that's not how you pass context to the template. You should pass a dictionary: `{'files': files}`.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaayyyyyy you are da man :D it worked :))) thank you dude ! by the way, can you tell me where you learned this stuff or can you recommend me some good tutorials ? thanks :) !

Comment: @ZedsWhatSheSaid : all this is documented : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/

Comment: the call to `os.chgdir` is useless, you can as well call `os.listdir()` on the desired directory. Also, `os.listdir` returns a list so iterating over it to populate another list is a pure waste of time and resources...

Comment: can anybody tell me why he used dict(files=files) ? I don't understand that one :/

Comment: This is something you should look up, but it's a function that creates a `dict` out of the arguments you pass in. The resulting dictionary will look like `{'files':files}`

Answer (score 3):

You can pass variable to template like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def index(request):
    os.chdir("/home/ubuntu/newproject/static")
    for file in os.listdir("."):
        files.append(file)
    return render_to_response('sslcert/index.html', {'files':files})
```

And in template you can use it like:

```
{{files}}
```

if you want to use whole field or you can loop through them

```
{% for file in files %}
# do something with file here
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I thank you for your answer :) but this gave me an Syntax Error. It tells me that there is an invalid Syntax in this line "return render_to_response('sslcert/index.html','files':files)". I hopefully placed the commands for the template at the right place, I placed them between the body tag and it looks like this at the moment: <body> {% for file in files %}
{% endfor %} </body> Edit: plus, I edited the new import as well; still does not work :/

Comment: that one does not give me an syntax error but still it is not working :/ it just gives me this line "Following directories are in this folder:" and then nothing follows up, but still thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

render function You are using in Your example got dictionary argument which can extend context passed into template

> render(request, template_name[, dictionary][, context_instance][, content_type][, status][, current_app][, dirs])
>
> dictionary
> A dictionary of values to add to the template context. By default, this is an empty dictionary. If a value in the dictionary is callable, the view will call it just before rendering the template.

so you can pass any data into template as dictionary which keys will be available in template as variable

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    dir = "/home/ubuntu/newproject/static"
    return render('sslcert/index.html', {'files': os.listdir(dir)})
```